# Command line equivalent to "Run Document" for R versions >= 3.2.2 so that markdown files can access the global environment

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am making an interactive R Markdown report, with Shiny providing the interactivity. I am having a problem where I cannot access variables in the global environment when I click "Run Document" in RStudio (as described [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html#creating_an_interactive_document)). That same sections describes how you can use `rmarkdown::run(...)` to run the document from the command line, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown) shows that this allows the report to access variables in the global environment.

However, for my version of R I get the following error in the pop up window:

> Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.

When I try and install `pandoc`, I get:

```
> install.packages("pandoc")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘pandoc’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: ah, now I feel a bit silly. My RStudio version is `0.99.484` so I am a bit behind (sept 2015) I guess.

Comment: updating Rstudio fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandoc isn't a R package. It's something you need installed on your system. RStudio provides it if you don't have it installed.  Updating RStudio should fix the issue if you don't want to install pandoc manually.