# How to use a variable inside a function in a R Rmarkdown file, using render

Tags: r, render, r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown file I knit with `rmarkdown::render` : I make all my data processing in the .R and then, I knit in a Rmd using function. My problem is, if I encapsulate the render function in order to make my code more readable, it doesn't work anymore. Here is a basic example :
- My .Rmd file :

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
printA()
```
````

My R Code that work :

```
library(rmarkdown)
a<- 5
printA <- function() {
  return(a)
}
render("c:/users/db7trs/desktop/test.Rmd")
```

but when I encapsulate that in a function, that doesn't work anymore :

```
library(rmarkdown)
printA <- function() {
  return(a)
}
rendre <- function(){
  a <- 5
  render("c:/users/db7trs/desktop/test.Rmd")
}

rendre()
```

With this code, I have a quite explicit error : `Quitting from lines 7-8 Error in printA() : object 'a' not found`.

This problem would be easily solved if I explicitly make a an argument of the printA function, which in this case would anyway be a good practice, but I don't understand why it works differently in this two cases.

Comment: You should provide code for printA, we guess what it is of course

Comment: oups sorry you're right, I've edited my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown

Comment: thank you I've seen this question, I frequently use the first solution (use render instead of knit), I find it better for the code to remain readable, and quick to execute : my data is processed, or load, one time, and in the Rmd I have nothing more than display problem. But I don't get why the a object declared in the "rendre" function can't be used in another function used in the Rmd.

Comment: Sorry I just stumbled on that link. Yes, sebastien is right, when you call render it evaluates what's in the parent frame, no problem, but your function printA accesses objects from .globalEnv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is more that the function `printA` is not declared inside your `rendre()` function. (Even if the error message speaks about `a`). Hence, you can declare your function inside `rendre()` or inside the `Rmd` file.

### Inside `rendre()` function

```
rendre <- function(){
  printA <- function() {
    return(a)
  }
  a <- 5
  render("c:/users/db7trs/desktop/test.Rmd")
}
```

### OR inside the `test.Rmd`

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
printA <- function() {
  return(a)
}
printA()
```
````

Comment: I am lost : your solution works, so I would like to agree that the problem is really with the function declaration, but on the other hand, if the function printA returns 1 instead of a, it also works although it shouldn't with your hypothesis (except if I misunderstood something)

Comment: True. There is something with Global vs Local environment, but I can't give you the exact explanation...