# Can you make R add data to global environment while knitting an R Markdown document?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am aware that R Markdown cannot reference data within your global environment unless they are part of your R Markdown script (see this question: [How to use objects from global environment in Rstudio Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown)).

However, I'm confused why Markdown does not add data to my global environment when I knit the Markdown document. For example, I can specify `x<- 75`, `y<- 200`, then calculate `x+y` in my Markdown, and all of these elements will run and display in my knitted R Markdown document. But none of them get added to my global environment. Is this intentional? Is there any way around it?

I am working in RStudio.