# My code will run as a chunk but gives me an error when I try to knit

Tags: r, knitr

Hi I'm new to R and I'm using RStudio Cloud for a university stats course.

The code I'm having trouble with will run as a chunk but when I try to knit the project it comes up with an error saying that the object 'filename' not found.

The 'filename' is listed in the global environment but it is a tbl_df, which I'm thinking is not the right kind of object for knitting.

[image: screencapture]

Comment: The knit button in Rstudio creates a new environment to do the knit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use objects from global environment in Rstudio Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown)

Comment: I read that thread and found that the suggested changes to the R Markdown Global environment settings was set to document in my project.

Comment: Did you attempt `rmarkdown::render("your_doc.Rmd")`?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer without having all the code. And code is almost always better than a screenshot.

My guess is that you loaded the dataset `X2019THBrier` manually in RStudio. Thus you can access it in chunks, in the current R session, but not in the knitted R session.

You need to write commands to load the data. As you are loading an XLSX file, you might want to install the [`openxlsx`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.1.0) package, and use the `openxlsx::read.xlsx()` command.

Comment: Tried as you suggested and now the error is a parse error (not that I have any idea what that means).