# blogdown how to ingore an Rmd file that was built previously

Tags: blogdown

I am using blogdown to build my site.

For a recent post, I wanted to keep a variable (`config`) out of the .Rmd post itself, because `config` contained sensitive authentication information.  If I set config globally, but not in the .Rmd file itself, calling `blogdown::serve_site()` failed because `config` was not defined in the new session `serve_site()` creates when rendering the markdown files.

To accomplish what I wanted, I manually rendered the .Rmd source file with `config` defined in the global environment by calling `rmarkdown::render("path/to/post.Rmd")`, as suggested in [how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown).  This successfully built the .Rmd file and produced the correct html output.

Now, though, I am unable to use `blogdown::serve_site()` to automatically build new posts on my site.  It continually fails on the post that does not contain the required `config` variable.  Is there a way to ignore the offending post?  Or alternatively, a better way to do this?

Comment: You almost never need to use `blogdown::build_site()`. Please see https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/workflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like how you set global R options for **blogdown** (see [Section 1.4 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/global-options.html)), you can create `config` in `.Rprofile` under the root directory of your website project. The R code in `.Rprofile` will be executed before each Rmd post is rendered.