# R markdown produces different output than R Code

Tags: r, environment-variables, r-markdown, pdf-generation, markdown

I am working on a project in R, and have created a markdown document (for PDF) for it. The document literally contains the same exact code as the .R file; Both the R Files and the Rmd files are in the same directory.

The purpose of the project is to create a predictive rating system. There are a few algorithms the code examines, picks the best one, checks it on a validation data set, and gets an expected result, very close to (and actually lower) then what the last version of the algorithm produced.

However, when this code is run inside the .Rmd file, the results are fairly significantly off.

I have tried some of the things recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown) :

I have specifically set the working directory with the "`here`" package and used `save.image()` to save the current environment; I've loaded the file into the markdown document to load the environment - that didn't work.

I have used the `rmarkdown::render()` command on my file to knit the file, after using the `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache =TRUE)` command.

When I run the `str(options())` command in both, I get very different outputs. This is the only thing I can think of at this point.

How do I get the `options()` to be the same in both files? Is there a setting for this in R Studio? I had thought that because both file are in the same location this wouldn't be a problem, but here I am...

EDIT:
I'm enclosing the links to my github code:

[R File](https://github.com/mganopolsky/r_final_harvard_data_science_project/blob/master/final_project.R)
[Rmd File](https://github.com/mganopolsky/r_final_harvard_data_science_project/blob/master/final_project.Rmd)

These are processing millions of lines of code, so they will take time. In the end, the output from the R File will have the following (or something similar:) - notice that the final RMSE value on the validation set Is lower then all the rest.

```
|method                                                                         |      RMSE|
|:------------------------------------------------------------------------------|---------:|
|Just the average                                                               | 1.0429393|
|Just Movie Effect Model b_i average                                            | 0.9390297|
|User Affect + Movie Effect Model                                               | 0.8556187|
|Regularized + Movie Effect                                                     | 0.9390291|
|Regularized Movie + User Effect Model                                          | 0.8555519|
|Regularized Movie + User Effect Model + Year Effect Model                      | 0.8552506|
|Regularized Movie + User Effect Model + Year Effect Model + Genre Effect Model | 0.8551794|
|Final Model Tested on Validation Set                                           | 0.8550428|
```

The output from the .Rmd file inevitably looks like this - notice the last RMSE higher then the few previous ones:

```
method RMSE
1 Just the average 1.0406546
2 Movie Effect Model 0.9266068
3 User Effect + Movie Effect Model 0.8440959
4 Regularized + Movie Effect 0.9266057
5 Regularized Movie + User Effect Model 0.8440903
6 Regularized Movie + User + Year Effect Model 0.8439340
7 Regularized Movie + User + Year + Genre Effect Model 0.8438856
8 Final Model Tested on Validation Set 0.8451003
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Please read [ask]. There's not much we can do with out a [mcve].

Comment: I've added some github links and some actual numerican output.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm having a similar issue and cannot locate the source of the problem.