# RStudio knit: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Tags: r, knitr

I'm trying to knit an RStudio notebook but i'm getting the following error:

> "Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function" Calls:  ... mutate -> log_mutate -> .fun -> mutate.default -> mutate_"

with the following lines:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    variable = factor(variable,ordered = FALSE)
  )
```

The funniest thing is that the R code works just fine and does the expected. Only the knitting doesn't work.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have `library(dplyr)` in the notebook? Rmarkdown knits in a new environment so packages used in the script need to be explicitly referenced. Alternatively try `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: Thank you @Peter! I have ```library(dplyr)``` in the notebook and i tried ```dplyr::mutate``` but i still get this error :(

Comment: Could you make the question reproducible by including the minimum code from your Notebook which consistently reproduces the error? I guess this would be the yaml and one code chunk which includes a minimal dataset.

Comment: This is because you didn't load `data` in your Markdown document, so that knit finds `utils::data()` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/34029611/13513328