# Unable to knit to HTML due to error "No applicable method for filter applied to an object of class

Tags: html, r, filtering

I have finished my code and it all runs well in Rmarkdown - however when I attempt to knit to html I receive an error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3895Z.png)

[Data link - kaggle page](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mcdonalds/nutrition-facts)

Any ideas on what m missing?

````
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(colourpicker)


```{r}
str(menu)
head(menu)
dim(menu)

#Filter outliers outside of 15 & 1151
menu2 <- menu %>% 
  filter(between(Calories, 15, 1151))

#Group together food categories
Category_groups <- menu2 %>% 
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Calories))
Category_groups

#Add column to categorise high, med, low calories
Category_groups$Cal_group <- factor(c('HIGH', 'LOW', 'HIGH', 'HIGH', 'MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM', 'HIGH', 'MEDIUM'))
```
````

Comment: Do you actually load the `menu` data in the Rmarkdown document itself? Because otherwise `menu` is a built in function from the {utils} package. There needs to be a line in the document where you load the data.

Comment: To understand why you get this error, this might help :https://stackoverflow.com/q/34029611/13513328

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: That's a good reference answer for this common problem, @Waldi, I'll remember that link.